# Bangla fonts are broken in iMovie

Tags: macos, font, imovie

I can write Bangla in iMovie but when I watch it as a video or, export it the fonts are broken. How can I fix it? Any help would be great.

I wrote two Bangla words like the first image and they are changed to following screenshot.

During editing:

[image]

After editing:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It worked http://www.ekushey.org/?page/osx_fonts.

Full discussion is here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/33855238?ac_cid=op123456#33855238